# Does a method count as an association?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class, uml, class-diagram

Taking into consideration this class diagram:

There is a "has a" (aggregation) between the two, if I'm not mistaken, because Library actually can hold a handle to an instance of a book.
[image]

Now, what about this diagram?

[image]

Is there an association between the two? LibraryService never stores an instance of Book in it, but one of it's method returns an array of books. What relationship would there be between the two classes?

On a related note, Visual studio does not seem to allow you to link methods to objects when it generates a class diagram. This is what led me to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an association between the two? LibraryService never stores an instance of Book in it

Then the answer is no. A relationship represents some kind of cooperation between the two classes, e.g. by exchanging messages or querying a status (Seemann 2006, p. 53, "UML2"). In this case, the two do not cooperate. Probably, your LibraryService only serves the Library which then has a connection to "book".

> but one of it's method returns an array of books.

You convey that information already in the method list - which is fine :)

If you wanted a relationship you'd have to be able to add semantics to it which in this case would just be redundant but less understandable.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can have a relationship here: a dependency, which is an anonymous dashed arrow. But as observer said, it is not really worth it since you already have the information in the method definition.

Comment: That's true! Sooner or later, there'll be a time when you're grateful for every connector that you could avoid (in a clever way!). And that's because it is not messing up your diagram by causing yet another crossing ;)